# why @model object physical path displaying in Razor View aps.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

In my mvc application `@model` physical path is getting displayed in output.

Is there any way to prevent not displaying model physical path ?

I have declare model in this way in view

```
@model VM_Quote_Project.Models.Users
@{
ViewBag.Title = "allusers";
Layout = "~/Views/Account/_AuthLayout.cshtml";
}
```

and

the output html is returning like this in top of the page.

```
using VM_Quote_Project.ViewModels
VM_Quote_Project.Models.Users BaseViewModel

<!DOCTYPE html>
```

Comment: I'd say that you are rendering the View at the wrong position in the HTML document. Could you edit the post so we can see the layout file as well.

Comment: Can you show the relevant part of `/_AuthLayout` layout ?